# Big Theta runtime analysis

Tags: math, big-o, discrete-mathematics

I don't really understand the 2 questions below about T(n). I understand what theta means but I'm not sure about the answer for the questions. Can someone explain?

I thought that first one was false because T(2n/3) + 1 = Theta(log n) because
the constant 1 added doesn't make a difference 
and log is closer to halving continuously but 2n/3 is not

I thought that second one was true because T(n/2) + n = Theta(n * log n) because
the linear "n *" in Theta represents the "+n" in T(n/2) + n
the "n/2" represents the log n in Theta...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**The first is Θ(log n).**
Intuitively, when you multiply n by a constant factor, T(n) increases by a constant amount. 
Example: T(n) = log(n)/log(3/2)

**The second is Θ(n).**
Intuitively, when you multiply n by a constant factor, T(n) increases by an amount proportional to n.
Example: T(n) = 2n

Comment: I just talked to my professor and they said first one = true and second one = false

Comment: @JigarPatel: Do you mean that the correct answer to the second of the two test questions you cite is "FALSE" (which is true), or that the second part of my Answer is *false* (which is false)? At times like this, it behooves us to speak precisely.